# file.table not found using lualatex but found with pdflatex

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex

I try to compile with lualatex the simple file :

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
   \begin{document}
          \begin{tikzpicture}
           \draw[color=blue]
            plot[id=sin,domain=0:6,samples=100] function{sin(x)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

The file `essai.sin.gnuplot` is created but not `essai.sin.table`.
My problem is that the code compiles very well with pdflatex.

Here the beginning of the file.log

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)
system commands enabled.
```

Some questions seem similar but I can't find a good answer.

Comment: This questions might be useful: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314483/pgfplots-contour-gnuplot-with-lualatex-instead-of-pdflatex (specifically, the `\usepackage{shellesc}` part)